# Ruby on rails link_to an image in assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, hyperlink, reference, assets

I'm sure there are many post like this but after to check them I wasn't found anyone to answer my issue.
Im trying to get an image located at `"app/assets/images/levers/I.a.1.png"` with a `link_to` like this:

`<%= link_to("Biomasa", image_path("levers/I.a.1.png"), :target => "_new") %>`

No matter how many times I tried with differents combinations of the path, it doesn't work. I'm getting this error:

`The asset "levers/I.a.1.png" is not present in the asset pipeline.`

There are something I'm missing or doing wrong?

**More information**

I'm not sure if is important but im using "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" to make all possible from my windows 10 (at work obiously).

Comment: What is the image name? Is it `image.png` or `I.a.1.png`?

Comment: is "I.a.1.png", sry about my last explanation, i edited it to make it more clear.

Comment: Try `asset_path` instead of `image_path`

Comment: @Pavan, with `asset_path` i get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solve this. The problem was a case sensitive in the extension of my images. It was `.PNG` and I was trying `.png`

Answer (score 1):

add this config to your `application.rb` to include files inside `app/assets/images` into asset pipeline

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "images", "levers")
```

Then, on your rails view, you can use `link_to` with `asset_path`

```
<%= link_to root_path, :target => "_blank" do %>
  <%= image_tag asset_path("I.a.1.png") %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Doing this i also get the same result :/

Comment: did you restart the server after that config update in `application.rb` ?

Comment: missed to add folder 'levers' .. can you try this ? `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "images", "levers")` .. updated the answer

Comment: unfontunaly, after that im still getting the same issue

Comment: Try changing the image filename to something readable without so many `.` characters like 'logo.png'

Comment: Tried with same results

Comment: you must have something else going on ..  have you customized any rails codebase like `ActionView::Base` module ? try pulling the code on a different machine and running it.

Comment: After to try a lot of things I saw a strange behaviour.
I cut the folder `levers` with all `.png` inside from `app/assets/images` and paste it in `public/images`, when i click the links to images in my view just work some of them (the first 4 or 5 i think).
The link in view is this `<%= link_to("Biomasa", image_path("/images/levers/I.a.1.png"), :target => "_new") %>`

Comment: Another interesting thing is as I said in the begining of the issue is I'm working in  "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows", that's mean Im locaten on Windows 10 but with a console of Ubuntu. For some reason that I doesnt know when i started the server in windows the images links work perfectly (if the images are in `public/images`) but if i started the server in ubuntu they doesnt work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a block to `link_to`. Try this:

```
<% link_to('/wherever/you/want/to/link-to', :target => '_new') do %>
  <%= image_tag('I.a.1.png', alt: 'Biomasa') %>
<% end %>
```

Image tag should look in `app/assets/images` automatically, so this will add the remainder of the path.

Add this to `config/initializers/assets.rb`

```
Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/**/").each do |path|
  Rails.application.config.assets.paths << path
end
```

and you should be good to go.

Comment: Added a little more. This works for a Rails app on my machine, so if that doesn't fix it something else is going on.

Comment: Okey, I began to think there is something else wrong because this doesn't work.
The problem is I dont have any idea of whts it is

Comment: Might have something to do with the image name. Try changing it to `1a1.png` and putting it in `assets/images`, and removing `levers/` from the image path. If it doesn't show up, please inspect the image path in your browser and paste the link in here

Comment: I tried with that changes and still getting the same... I can't inspect the image path in the browser because it doesn't reach to load, instead that I get the error wich I mentioned in the begin with the proper changes